# How to Make Shader In Unity 2022.3 URP receive shadow from environment and from it surface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, urp

i am working on AnimMap for Animation using GPU instade of CPU and Everything work as good as i wish but there is porblem with shader,see i have zero experince in shader using c# in unity so i get the shader from this page in github : https://github.com/chenjd/Render-Crowd-Of-Animated-Characters
and i try to make object receive shadow but i couldnt make it reivce shadow
here the script of shader  :

/*
Created by jiadong chen
https://jiadong-chen.medium.com/
*/

```
`Shader "chenjd/URP/AnimMapWithShadowShader"
{
     Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}

        [Header(AnimMap)]
        _AnimMap("AnimMap", 2D) = "white" {}
        _AnimLen("Anim Length", Float) = 0
        _Tim("Time", Float) = 0

    }

    CGINCLUDE
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

sampler2D _MainTex;
float4 _MainTex_ST;

struct appdata
{
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
};

struct v2f
{
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
};

fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
 
        // Lighting calculations (Lambertian lighting)
    float3 lightDir = normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);
    float3 normal = normalize(1);
    float diff = max(0.0, dot(normal, lightDir));
    col.rgb *= diff;

    return col;
}

struct v2fShadow
{
    V2F_SHADOW_CASTER;
        UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
    };

    float4 fragShadow(v2fShadow i) : SV_Target
    {
        SHADOW_CASTER_FRAGMENT(i)

    }

    sampler2D _AnimMap;
    float4 _AnimMap_TexelSize; // x == 1/width
    float _AnimLen;
    float _Tim;

    v2f vert(appdata v, uint vid : SV_VertexID)
    {
        UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);

        float f = _Tim + (_Time.y / _AnimLen);
        fmod(f, 1.0);

        float animMap_x = (vid + 0.5) * _AnimMap_TexelSize.x;
        float animMap_y = f;

        float4 pos = tex2Dlod(_AnimMap, float4(animMap_x, animMap_y, 0, 0));

        v2f o;
        o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
        o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(pos);
        return o;
    }
    ENDCG

    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
        Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalRenderPipeline"
    }
            Tags { "LightMode" = "UniversalForward"
}
            Cull
off
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            //开启gpu instancing
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
Name"ShadowCaster"
            Tags
{"LightMode" = "ShadowCaster"
}

LOD 100

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment fragShadow
            #pragma target 2.0
            #pragma multi_compile_shadowcaster
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}`
```

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.